# pyspark crosstab with percentages

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, data-analysis, crosstab

I have a DataFrame after applying crosstab in the pyspark, Example Below

| id | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cssdsd | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| sdsdsd | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| ssdssd | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| xxxxxx | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Instead of 0,1's I want to get the percentages of the rows.
I can be easily get that with the pandas using the crosstab function

```
pd.crosstab(df.index,df.list, normalize='index')
```

How can I get this in pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the crosstab result which is `df` in the below code. Get sum of all columns except `id` and then divide each column with the sum:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = [i for i in df.columns if not i=='id']
out = (df.withColumn("SumCols",F.expr('+'.join(cols)))
.select("id",*[F.coalesce(F.round(F.col(i)/F.col("SumCols"),2),F.lit(0)).alias(i) 
                                                                 for i in cols]))
```

---

```
out.show()

+------+----+----+----+
|    id|   A|   B|   C|
+------+----+----+----+
|cssdsd| 0.0| 1.0| 0.0|
|sdsdsd|0.33|0.33|0.33|
|ssdssd| 1.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|xxxxxx| 0.0| 0.0| 0.0|
+------+----+----+----+
```

Note that you can multiply by 100 in the select statement loop if necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. For the above example data, it is working fine, but when I apply it with the real data, it is throwing an error
```
ParseException: 
mismatched input '+' expecting {, '-'}(line 1, pos 17)

== SQL ==
```

Comment: @HAthedatascientist this should work if  your data is as in the example. Hard to debug without seeing the original data but the idea will remain the same

Comment: There was an error in col names so it was throwing an error. col names shouldn't have any spaces or characters. Thanks! It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.crosstab(col1='index', col2='list').show()
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer and how it solves the issue.

Comment: This is not really an answer, as the question was about getting this in pyspark.